# i was running the server and suddenly it started throwing error

Tags: node.js

idont know what to do

node:events:492
throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
^

Error: listen EACCES: permission denied 3000;
at Server.setupListenHandle [as _listen2] (node:net:1855:21)
at listenInCluster (node:net:1920:12)
at Server.listen (node:net:2019:5)
at Function.listen (C:\Users\navee\Desktop\pettycash-manager\Petty_Cash_manager_Backend-main\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:635:24)
at C:\Users\navee\Desktop\pettycash-manager\Petty_Cash_manager_Backend-main\server.js:46:9
at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
Emitted 'error' event on Server instance at:
at emitErrorNT (node:net:1899:8)
at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21) {
code: 'EACCES',
errno: -4092,
syscall: 'listen',
address: '3000;',
port: -1
}

Node.js v20.10.0

Comment: There's plenty of information in the error message to start debugging, IMO. What do you struggle with exactly?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

start find out if the port you are using is free

## On Unix-like systems (Linux/macOS)

lsof -i :3000

## On Windows

netstat -ano | findstr :3000